# TypeError "versionchange" when using indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Thanks a lot for you advice Kristof, I correct my code :

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;
var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;

const dbName = "mediasDB";

const db_store = "medias";

var db;


function openDB(dbName, dbVersion) {

    var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {

        console.log("Upgrade");
        console.log('Creating objectStore');

        var store = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(db_store);

        store.transaction.oncomplete = function (evt) {

            storeMedias(mediaData, function (media) {
                var store = getObjectStore(db_store, "readwrite")
                console.log(media);
                store.put(media, media.url);
                console.log("Rajout d'un media dans la BD");
            });
        };  
    };

    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        console.log("openDB DONE");
        db = this.result;       
    };

    request.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log(event.target.result);
    };
}


openDB(dbName, 1);


//On déclenche le défilement des médias au bout de 5 secondes

setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON("remoteFileJson", function (data) {

         if (data.revision != db.version) {
            console.log('Mise à jour de la BD');
            openDB(dbName, data.revision);

         } else {
            console.log('La base de données est à jour');
         }
    });
}, 10000);
```

Each ten seconds, I get a JSON which give me my number of revision (it's greater than my db.version I check), but when I reOpenDB, there is no call to upgradeneeded.

Comment: var db,;  I think , after db is typo ??

Comment: No it was a mistake sorry. var db;

Comment: current problem now is probably the fact you are blocked because your first db connection is still open and has to be closed before you can upgrade.

Comment: I have found an alternative solution without versioning. Thanks for help, I'll edit if I find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a versionchange transaction manually. The only way to invoke this is by changing the version number when opening the indexeddb connection. for more info: http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/01/indexed-db-defining-your-structure-new.html

```
var dbRequest = indexeddb.open("name", 3);
dbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e)
{
    var versionChangeTrans = e.target.transaction;
}
```